# Percentage Change in Json Dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm learning python and i want to understand how to assign
a value of ascending and descending order to 2 different
variables.

In this case i would use both variables one with highest wins
the other with the lowest wins to get the percentage change:

the api list content looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "team_id": "FALCONS",
    "time_data": "2018-05-06T15:25:36.9524691Z",
    "wins": 11,
    "crow_size": 19563,
    "last_game": {
      "time_data": "2018-05-06T15:17:16.0000000Z",
      "data": "4e7a-bf0c-a97e5f32f58b",
      "take_side": "NA"
    }
  },
  {
    "team_id": "CARDINALS",
    "time_data": "2018-05-06T15:25:36.9212380Z",
    "wins": 14,
    "crow_size": 26000,
    "last_game": {
      "time_data": "2018-05-06T15:25:25.6850000Z",
      "data": "42ec-8326-445a22ea460f",
      "take_side": "NA"
    }
  },
  {
    "team_id": "BUFFALO",
    "time_data": "2018-05-06T15:25:36.7961978Z",
    "wins": 16,
    "crow_size": 34200,
    "last_game": {
      "time_data": "2018-05-06T15:07:50.0000000Z",
      "data": "44b7-86c1-6b969fccbe2e",
      "take_side": "NA"
    }
  },
  {
    "team_id": "COWBOYS",
    "time_data": "2018-05-06T15:25:36.9524691Z",
    "wins": 21,
    "crow_size": 15563,
    "last_game": {
      "time_data": "2018-05-06T15:17:16.0000000Z",
      "data": "4e7a-bf0c-a97e5f32f58b",
      "take_side": "NA"
    }
  },
  {
    "team_id": "DETROIT-LIONS",
    "time_data": "2018-05-06T15:25:36.9212380Z",
    "wins": 17,
    "crow_size": 23000,
    "last_game": {
      "time_data": "2018-05-06T15:25:25.6850000Z",
      "data": "42ec-8326-445a22ea460f",
      "take_side": "NA"
    }
  },
  {
    "team_id": "DOLPHINS",
    "time_data": "2018-05-06T15:25:36.7961978Z",
    "wins": 22,
    "crow_size": 24200,
    "last_game": {
      "time_data": "2018-05-06T15:07:50.0000000Z",
      "data": "44b7-86c1-6b969fccbe2e",
      "take_side": "NA"
    }
  }
]
```

It's a really large list, so i only want an specific number of teams
not all of them, so then i can do my percentage change math

```
import requests
import json
import time
import datetime
import heapq
from pprint import pprint
from operator import itemgetter


url = 'api url'
data = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(data.content)

data.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('wins'), reverse=True)


lookup = ["CARDINALS", "BUFFALO", "DOLPHINS", "COWBOYS"]



for item in data:
    teamname = item["team_id"]
    winstreak = item["wins"]
    for ex in lookup:
        if ex == teamname:
            print(teamname, winstreak)
```

So far what i'm able to do is print out just the key and value
with the above formula, can anyone help me get the percentage change
of the highest wins to the lowest wins?

Comment: There is no `score` key in any of the team dictionaries. Do you mean the value associated with the `wins` key?

Comment: yes, score means wins sorry about that

Comment: for the example values in the question, what would be the output for "percentage change of the highest wins to the lowest wins"?

Comment: @JrDavid, I wanted to suggest a possible answer to a recent question you asked "Python Loop In Json Dictionaries" that was deleted which used the `lomond` package. Not sure why you deleted it, or maybe you already got it working, but here is a possible working version for your code:  https://repl.it/@downshift/CircularTomatoDecimal. Not sure if produces your desired output. Just thought I would share it with you.

Answer (score 0):

Given your range of teams, you can use `min` and `max`:

```
import json
lookup = ["CARDINALS", "BUFFALO", "DOLPHINS", "COWBOYS"]
url = 'api url'
data = requests.get(url)
team_data = json.loads(data.content)
new_teams = [i for i in team_data if i['team_id'] in lookup]
min_win = min(new_teams, key=lambda x:x['wins'])['wins']
max_win = max(new_teams, key=lambda x:x['wins'])['wins']
change_win = (max_win-min_win)/float(min_win+max_win)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may help:

```
lookup = ["CARDINALS", "BUFFALO", "DOLPHINS", "COWBOYS"]

wins = {}  # dictionary for team wins

for item in data:
    teamname = item["team_id"]
    winstreak = item["wins"]
    for ex in lookup:
        if ex == teamname:
            wins.update({teamname: winstreak}) # add team wins to dictionary
            print(teamname, winstreak)

low = min(wins.values())   # minimum of team wins
high = max(wins.values())  # maximum of team wins
print('low: {}, high: {}'.format(low, high))
print('percent difference: {}'.format(float(high-low)/low)) # print the percentage
```

output:

```
CARDINALS 14
BUFFALO 16
COWBOYS 21
DOLPHINS 22
low: 14, high: 22
percent difference: 0.571428571429
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from __future__ import division # for python 2

hWin = None
for item in data:
    teamname = item["team_id"]
    winstreak = item["wins"]
    if teamname in lookup:
        if not hWin:
            hWin = winstreak
        percentChange = (hWin - winstreak) / hWin * 100
        print(teamname, winstreak,  '%i%%' % percentChange)
```

will result

```
('DOLPHINS', 22, '0%')
('COWBOYS', 21, '4%')
('BUFFALO', 16, '27%')
('CARDINALS', 14, '36%')
```